# Print XML as table in Bash

Tags: bash, xml

When I have an XML file like this:

```
<guests>
    <guest>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <music>Silence</music>
        <dish>Vegetables</dish>
        <beverage>Water</beverage>
    </guest>
    <guest>
        <name>Brutus</name>
        <music>Verdi</music>
        <dish>Meat</dish>
        <beverage>Mulsum</beverage>
    </guest>
</guests>
```

Is there already an elegant bash-y way of formatting this into a table? I imagine it like this:

```
cat myPartyGuests.xml | xmlToTable --lines "/guests/guest" --columns "name, beverage, dish"
```

that gives something like this:

```
name   beverage dish
Adam   Water    Vegetables
Brutus Mulsum   Meat
```

I already know that if I could get the XML into a form like this:

```
name;beverage;dish
Adam;Water;Vegetables
Brutus;Mulsum;Meat
```

...I can use `column -s\; -t` to get exactly my desired output, so only the "XML to CSV" step is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use XSL transformations [using XSL stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt).

Or write a simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import untangle, sys

data = untangle.parse(sys.stdin.read())

print(" ".join(["name", "beverage", "dish"]))
for guest in data.guests.guest:
    print(" ".join([guest.name.cdata, guest.beverage.cdata, guest.dish.cdata]))
```

Install `untangle` with `pip3 install --user untangle`, make the script executable, and run:

```
$ ./test.py < myPartyGuests.xml
Adam Water Vegetables
Brutus Mulsum Meat
```

Or use `xmltodict`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xmltodict, sys

data = xmltodict.parse(sys.stdin.read())

fields = ["name", "beverage", "dish"]

print(" ".join(fields))
print("\n".join(" ".join(guest[f] for f in fields) for guest in data["guests"]["guest"]))
```

I'm using `untangle` or `xmltodict` instead of builtin XML libraries because I find those easier to use. This can be done with any other scipting language, of course.

Comment: This is cool!! :-) I am thinking of making a generic version of that, but I do not have the time now. Just great. =)